# How to tell cracked servers from genuine servers hosting these FPS games? 

Tags: first-person-shooter

In brief, I want to know whether there are any local cracked servers (hosted in my geographic location) for some games I am considering - like Call of Duty series, Counter Strike, Unreal Tournament etc.

Let me mention, I am **not** looking to setup a cracked server or support piracy.

I know that there are cracked servers listed in various sites like http://www.epcgaming.com etc. And I guess cracked servers do not appear in the list of servers while playing a game (in the game's interface).

Now, there are lots of sites like http://www.gametracker.com , http://www.game-monitor.com/, etc. which display lists of public game servers. Do you guys know whether they list cracked servers too. If so, how to tell which of them are cracked servers without actually having an installation of the game.

All this is part of my analysis before spending money for a public game server. Please look at my previous question for details https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/20233/6421.

I am looking to setup a public server for some Call of Duty version or some other FPS game, for players in India. I am yet to decide this based on the popularity of these games among players.

Comment: Quit beating around the bush and ask what you want to know.  So many words, so little said.

Comment: @Nick T - Is it? I have clearly asked "How to tell cracked servers from genuine servers?"

Comment: What game?  What then is the point of the remaining 80% of your post.

Comment: @Nick T - I knowingly asked a generic question, which can apply for all multiplayer games. Ok, adding Call of Duty in the beginning of the question. But I want to do this for several FPS games. Thanks

Comment: you contradict yourself. First you say you don't want to set up a private server, next you say you do want to set up a private server. There's no difference between 'cracked' and 'private' servers. If the game doesn't allow by design for people to set up their own servers, all such servers are 'cracked'. If it does, people won't bother to 'crack' anything and use the official mechanism provided.

Answer (score 1):

gametracker.com lists cracked servers. Regarding this website:

- You can find cracked servers by their name: "Cracked" or "No steam" is present in server name. And vice-versa, legal servers contain "Steam", "Official"
- Almost every server have its website with statistics, files etc, you can go to its website and check if it is a legal server.
- If you have the legal game installed you won't be able to connect to the cracked server. You can try to connect to those servers listed on gametracker.